# Android: setIndicatorBounds in Jelly Bean or higher

Tags: android, api, expandablelistview

I have created an app with a `custom ExpandableListView`. It works fine. But I have readed that in Jelly Bean `setIndicatorBounds` not works fine. I work with:

- minSdkVersion: 14
- targetSdkVersion: 18

I have tried this but it give me an error:

**Call requires API level 18 (current min is 14): android.widget.ExpandableListView#setIndicatorBoundsRelative**

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int anchoPantalla = metrics.widthPixels;

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {

        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(40), 
                anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(10));

    } else {
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(40), 
                anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
    }
```

How I can fix my error and my code works fine from Jelly Bean? Thanks

Comment: i also have the same issue, please anyone guide us ?

Answer (score 1):

```
...
      DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int anchoPantalla = metrics.widthPixels;

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {

        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(40), 
                anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(10));

    } else {
        JB_setIndicatorBoundsRelative(anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(40), 
                anchoPantalla - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
    }
}    
    ...

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private void JB_setIndicatorBoundsRelative(int left, int right)
    {
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(left, right);
    }
```